# Difference between data extractor agents and dms agents in AWS SCT

Tags: aws-sct

I am bit confuse between the different kind of agents present in AWS SCT archive. I am using 1.0.624 version of SCT.

1. agents - data extractors tool rpm
2. dms agents - dms agent rpm

As per my understanding both of them are used to extract data from data warehouse (on-premise or RDS instance) to Amazon Redshift in two steps . First the agent copies the data to s3 or snowball and from there it get copied to Redshift.

Now my question is what's the difference between two. Why there are different agents present in AWS SCT archive ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

1. agents - data extractors tool rpm <-- this is used by SCT to perform the one-time extraction and transfer to S3, Redshift, etc. described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/agents.html
2. dms agents - dms agent rpm <-- this is used by the DMS service with Snowball edge, described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_LargeDBs.Process.html

I agree the documentation could be improved.